# Extrair parte de URL com PHP

Tags: php, url

Preciso pegar uma parte de determinada URL e guardar em uma variável mas não sei como fazer com PHP, é a parte que está o nome da loja, existem várias lojas cadastradas, ai preciso pegar o nome depois do desconto/ e antes da última /.

https://www.localhost.com/desconto/nome-da-loja/

Comment: Leia sobre a função `parse_url`.

Comment: Por que tu não passa via `get`? cria o link pra o endereço " `https://www.localhost.com/desconto.php?nome_loja=nome-da-loja` " e depois recupera usando $_GET['nome_loja']. Sei que não é a melhor alternativa, mas pode ser interessante

Comment: Resolvi com o `.explode`, guardei numa variável e deu certo. Obrigado, galera.

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar simplesmente regex, desde que a URL do site seja "fixa", fazendo algo como:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.localhost.com/desconto/nome-da-loja/';

if (preg_match('#^https?:\/\/www\.localhost\.com\/desconto\/([^\/]+)\/#', $url, $matches)) {
    $loja = $matches[1];

    var_dump($loja);
} else {
    echo 'URL invalida';
}
```

Ressaltando, desde que a URL "seja fixa" e só o nome da loja mude.

A regex é simples, cada ponto é necessário escapar porque o `.` é usado como um tipo de curinga

O `([^\/]+)` é um grupo, esse grupo pega qualquer coisa que não contenha `/`, o sinal `^` indica que tem que ser diferente do que esta dentro de `[...]` e o sinal de `+` no final do grupo indica que tem que pegar tudo até o próximo *match* da regex (a parte seguinte da regex é o `\/`, antes do `#`)

O `#` em php é usado para delimitar apenas, não tem haver com a regex usada em si.

Se esta usando com `.htaccess` pode pegar através do `REQUEST_URI`, fazendo algo como (mais simples):

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (preg_match('#^/desconto\/([^\/]+)\/#', $url, $matches)) {
    $loja = $matches[1];

    var_dump($loja);
} else {
    echo 'URL invalida';
}
```